# react native how to store pic and username when using firebase to create a user with email and password

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to do an authentication (login and logout), but the method of `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` can only pass two parameters, I also want to pass the `username` and user `profilePic` to firebase and stored by it, so when login, the corresponding profilePic and user name can be displayed. I searched a lot online and made a little change on the code like below but it doesn't work at all.

[image]

How to pass the data to firebase and retrive from firebase?

And there is another problem which is everytime when I successfully registered as new user, it suppose to go to the next page to upload the picture, but it didn't, it just jump to the `RootPage`.

[image]

Even when I added on line like like `(this.props.navigation.push('PhotoPage'))`, every time when I finished the registration it will go to the `<PhotoPage/>` first, but it just show one second, then it automatically jump to `<Root/>`.

I think the method of `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` is running in the background, so every time when I successfully crated a new user, that method `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` will detect that user is not null, then it will return `<Root/>`. How to turn it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to reformat this question to be more clear. As per your first question, createUser.. only 'creates' the user within the firebase LOGIN. You then, and should at the same time store your user into the database with relevant signup data...

Here is an example of my singup action I use to create a user, then store to the database...

```
export const signupRequest = (email, password, username) => dispatch => {
// ******** The signup actions only trigger for first time users, no need to check database ********
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((authData) => {
        // ******** Firebase will create a route with whatever KEY is fed to the .set method ********
        // ******** We dont actually want this to avoid deep nesting ********
        // ******** So we package up our user.account object and .set(account) without any key value pairs ********
        let account = {}
        account.email = email.toLowerCase()
        account.uid = authData.uid
        account.username = username
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + authData.uid).set({
            account
        }).then(() => {
            // ******** Now we need to grap a snapshot from the DB to validate account creation and update the redux store locally ********
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + authData.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                let updatedUser = snapshot.val();
            }).then(() => {
                dispatch(userSet(updatedUser));

            })
        })
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

};

Then a Login example...

```
export const loginRequest = user => dispatch => {
// ******** This gets called in RootContainer on mount, it will populate redux store with the entire User object from firebase ********
// ******** Here we need to check if user already exists in Firebase Database so that we dont overwrite their old data ********
// ******** WARNING! With Firebase if you set data to a spot that has existing data it will overwrite it! ********
firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    // ******** This method is straight from their docs ********
    // ******** It returns whatever is found at the path xxxxx/users/user.uid ********
    let username = snapshot.val();

    // ******** Otherwise, the user already exists and we should update redux store with logged in user ********
    { !username.account ? console.log('errrrrrrrrr') : dispatch(userSet(username)) }
})
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

And in the above, you would have access to anything you saved, such as profile image or username from the username variable.

Comment: Hi Thanks for help, I will try your way, and I just reformat my question, hope it is more clear now

Comment: but Gavin, how can I get the userNam when i login?

Comment: You would use the UID you get from their login to fetch the data from your database... It's literally the final .then in the example. I will post my login example above. And totally NOT being rude or condescending, just stating, this is pretty basic firebase manipulation, maybe you would benefit from watching a video course or something?

Comment: Ja, I did search in firebase official document and i did't find about relevant method, all is just a very simple method who to pass the password and email using firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword. Maybe there is kind of video that I didn't find online, mostly I just search demo instead of video, but will try. May be for you it is basic, but for a new guy like me, usually it is struggling at the first time

Comment: Yea, no problem, here is a hackernoon tutorial from 2018. This should be great info, just read through if you don't have time to do the whole tutorial.. https://hackernoon.com/the-easiest-way-by-far-to-build-a-real-react-firebase-web-app-5dc6fa6f1b61

Comment: @GavinThomas How do you checking a already exist user ? user with same email id can use two separate account so how to handle it?